# Запуск процесса в c++

Tags: c++, процесс

Как мне запустить стандартную утилиту dumpbin внутри своего приложения на c++?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [`system`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system):

```
std::system("path\\to\\dumpbin.exe /exports \"path\\to\\your\\library.dll\"");
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. задача решена.